# Remove end marker from press release template in newlfm

Tags: newlfm

I'm trying to remove the end marker `# # #` that gets printed automatically at the end of the press release template in the following newlfm example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,pressrelease]{newlfm}
\usepackage{charter}
\newcommand{\subtitle}{This is a subtitle.}
\makeletterhead{Uiuc}{\Cheader{\vspace{16pt}my title}} 
\lthUiuc 
\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
my body
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

According to [the documentation](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/newlfm/newlfm.pdf), the command `\PhrPREnd` is supposed to print it but I'm not calling it in my tex file nor in the `prsrls.tex` if I use one (not required). I tried to use that command thinking that I could override the printed markers with empty space but I'm getting the "Undefined control sequence" error. Any ideas?

Comment: just call it in the preable with an empty argument: `\PhrPRend{}`. It didn't work for you because you have capitalized it wrong, its `\PhrPRend{}` not `\PhrPREnd{}`

Comment: Well the documentation is wrong then. It says `\PhrPREnd{}`. How did you figure out it was `\PhrPRend` instead?

Comment: I looked at the source, i.e. `newlfm.cls`

Comment: Oh. Did not know those were accessible. :)

Comment: I made it into answer since others can be confused by the wrong capitalization in the docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in the documentation of the `newlfm` class:

[image]

the command that creates the `###` is not `\PhrPREnd`, as stated, but `\PhrPRend`. This can be seen in the `newlfm.cls` file:

```
def\@am@phr{
%[...]
\PhrPRend{\# \# \#}% line 430
}
```